# Build all tables within testing database from schema.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to implement testing and realized I need to create a testing database.

- I successfully created the `schema.rb` file from the database by running `rake db:schema:dump`.
- I also successfully created the new testing database.

Now what I need to do (I think) is do something like a `rake db:schema:load`, but I want to specify that I am doing this for the test database (not the development database or the production database. I don't want to delete any of the data there!)

I attempted `rake db:test:schema:load` but that was not working.

Searches online advise using commands that appear to be deprecated for rails 4.1 or later.

---

**Answer based on feedback:**

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:schema:load
```

Comment: `rake db:test:prepare`

Comment: Also you don't need to manually create a `schema.rb` file. It is created when your run `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specify that you are creating the "test" database:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create
```

The RAILS_ENV environmental variable will allow you to specify which *environment* you wish to use.  These environments will be defined in your "config/database.yml".  Ensure that you have a test environment setup and a database specified under it.  This can be done to any task that you would like to affect a particular environment.

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake any:task:here
```